I am getting an error after adding Laravel Excel Provider
I am using SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel package in my Laravel project.
I am getting;
` BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application::share does not exist.
error.`

composer.json:
"require": {
"php": "^8.2",
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
"maatwebsite/excel": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
"fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
"laravel/breeze": "^2.1",
"laravel/pint": "^1.13",
"laravel/sail": "^1.26",
"mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
"nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^11.0.1"
},


app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withProviders([
        \Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
    ])
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();


I couldn't solve the error. No matter if I added it to the bootstrap/providers.php file or config/app.php, the error persists.

Looks like you're using an ancient version of maatwebsite/excel which is not supported by your laravel version. See support table: https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel?tab=readme-ov-file#wrench-supported-versions
